# AMPL – force one variable if a specific variable is active (multiple conditions?)

Tags: conditional-statements, ampl

Looking to connect two given variables in AMPL where if e.g. team 10 is chosen then team 12 also has to be chosen and vice versa. One of these cannot be selected without the other one also being selected.

Also what is the term to describe this situation? Multiple criteria? Conditional? Complementary?

Edit: working with binaries if that makes a difference.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
subject to c1: x[10] = x[12];
```

where `x` is your "selection" variable (adapt as needed). It's just a "constraint".